# kinesis data stream performance testing with partition key

Tags: amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I am using the Kinesis Data Generator tool and I was wondering how to define the partition key in the test data so that the data is distributed to all the shard evenly.

https://awslabs.github.io/amazon-kinesis-data-generator/web/producer.html

Comment: I use that tool. It already distributes data evenly (probably generates a unique id per record). You don't need to worry about that.

Comment: Can confirm by enabling shard-level metrics specifically incoming records, I was able to see in cloud watch that the records are roughly distributed evenly among the shards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool already distributes data evenly which can be verified by enabling shard-level metrics specifically the incoming records metric.